# How to uninstall Qt5 commercial license

Tags: qt, open-source, licensing, pyqt5

I got quite desperate on this, because I cannot install the open source Qt5 after I installed commercial Qt5 on my laptop.

This issue happened like this: My first trial of install Qt5, I chose the commercial license. Then when I tried to install PyQt5, it said my Qt5 license is commercial, not compatible with PyQt5 license. So naturally, as a open source lover, I uninstalled the Qt5. And reinstalled an open source version. But, no matter how many times I tried, PyQt5 says my Qt5 is still commercial license.

Dose anyone encounter the same issue here? And how did you solve it?
(I guess my last shot would be install a VM, but I sincerely hope I don't need to do that).

**Updates:** (July 28, 2015)

The issues turns out to be PyQt5 is not compatible with the newest Qt 5.5.0 at the moment. Choose a older version of Qt.

Comment: I never had a commercial version of qt. But do you possibly remember where you installed the license file? Maybe it is still on your system and you need to delete it.

Comment: I couldn't remember I installed a license specifically. I just installed the commercial Qt5 at my user folder as default, and that has been completed removed. @xsquared

Comment: In this guide for a Qt installation on Linux a license installation is mentioned: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/linux-building.html. Search your system for the **.qt-license** file, maybe it was installed automatically? It would also be helpful to tell us your OS.

Comment: sign..I couldn't find the **.qt-license** file in my home directory or anywhere else

Comment: @ma-码. Please edit your question and add the full output from running `python configure.py -w`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of days ago,when I install PyQt5 in osx(10.9.5) the same problem came to me.I install qt-opensource-mac-x64-clang-5.5.0.dmg,and when I install PyQt-gpl-5.5.tar.gz,it said that Qt5 license is commercial, not compatible with PyQt5 license.So i just remove the Qt5.5 by "rm -rf Qt5.5",then i install qt-opensource-mac-x64-clang-5.4.1.dmg,at last everything works Ok.I googled but din't find something useful.maybe pyqt5 din't support the latest Qt5's license,but Qt5 has GPL and LGPL,pyqt5 has GPL,it should worked...ok,just gussing,hope this will helpful

Comment: Thanks for your reply Alen. Let me give a try, my computer environment is the same with you, I believe your suggestion should work.

Comment: Welcome to SO, congratulates for 100 score breakthrough!